# Loop over R data frames and rename all variables to lowercase

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to convert the variable names of multiple datasets to all lower case.

```
names(data1) <- tolower(names(data1))
```

That works for any single dataset, but I have not figured out how to loop over datasets to do it to multiple files. Here is a for loop I attempted (I also tried with `lapply` but did not have any luck).

```
data_list <- c('data1', 'data2', 'data3')
for (file in data_list) {
    names(file) <- tolower(names(file))
}
```

I also tried:

```
data_list <- list('data1', 'data2', 'data3')
for (file in data_list) {
    names(file) <- tolower(names(file))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can in fact be done with lapply to iterate over all data frames and, since you mentioned dplyr, its proper syntax for this case, i.e. all variable names as lower case.

```
data_list <- list(iris, mtcars)

data_list_lower <- lapply(data_list, function(data) {
  data %>% 
    rename_with(tolower, .cols = everything()) # default is also everything()
})
```

For harmonizing variable names also have a look at the `snakecase` package which allows also for various other kinds of transformation

Comment: Or more succinctly (and using `purrr`), `map(data_list, ~ rename_with(., tolower))`. Or without `purrr`, then `lapply(data_list, rename_with, tolower)`.

Comment: Indeed the pipe is certainly not necessary here. However, maybe your lapply solution is a little bit t0o concise

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a sequence inside the for-loop `1:length(dataset_names)` for a list of df's and then rename `names()` inside the loop:

```
data_list <- list(data1, data2, data3)

for(i in 1:length(dataset_names)){
  
  names(data_list[[i]]) <-  tolower(names(data_list[[i]]))
  
  
}
```

**column names after applying loop**

```
for(i in 1:length(data_list)){
  print(names(data_list[[i]]))
}

#[1] "a" "b"
#[1] "c" "d"
#[1] "g" "h"
```

**data**

```
data1 <- data.frame(A = rep(1:3),
                    B = rep(1:3))

data2 <- data.frame(C = rep(1:3),
                    D = rep(1:3))

data3 <- data.frame(G = rep(1:3),
                    H = rep(1:3))
```

Comment: `data_list` doesn't have names, so the second line doesn't seem to do anything. Also, the elements of `data_list` are character strings instead of data frames, so its' not clear what the loop is doing.